# Jailbreak an iPad 1 on a PowerMac G4?

Tags: ipad, jailbreak, powerpc

Is it possible to jailbreak an iPad 1 on a PowerPC?

I've tried Greenpois0n on PowerPC, but for some reason that doesn't work, so is there any other software I can use?

(iPad is running iOS 5)

Answer (score 2):

[Absinthe 2.0.4](https://sites.google.com/site/greenpois0nabsinthe/absinthe-mac-2.0.4.dmg) has support for PowerPC. [It works on iOS 5.0 - 5.1.1](http://www.redmondpie.com/jailbreak-5.1.1-untethered-iphone-4s-ipad-3-ipod-touch-and-more-using-absinthe-2.0-video-tutorial/).